# Progression of the reciprocal of squares $ \lt \frac{1}{4}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, summation

$$\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{25}+\frac{1}{36}+\frac{1}{121}\cdots \lt\frac{1}{4}$$
This is an interesting summation in which the addition of the next term must make the sum  $\lt\frac{1}{4}$. All terms must be the reciprocal of squares $\gt2$. The first term really wouldn't be 1/4 because $\frac{1}{4}\not\lt\frac{1}{4}$. After the term $\frac{1}{36}$, it wouldnt't be $\frac{1}{49}$ because of the before-discussed rules and that 1/49 would make the sum (again) $\not\lt$ 1/4. Now the question:

If $f(1)=\frac{1}{9}$

$f(2)=\frac{1}{16}$

$f(3)=\frac{1}{25}$

$f(4)=\frac{1}{36}$

$f(5)=\frac{1}{121}$

and so on...

Is there a function that applies to this through all possible terms?
In other words, does f(n)=nth term a feasible function?

Comment: Can someone enlighten me why people think this sequence, along with the $\frac{1}{p} < 1$ sequence posted recently, qualifies as interesting? As far as I'm concerned, the sequence itself is not interesting since it's a completely arbitrary requirement (why $\frac{1}{4}$? why not $1$? or $\frac{1}{2}$? or $\frac{\pi^2}{12}$?). It would be interesting if the sequence formed had some relation to another sequence somehow so we could ask "why is there this relation?" but otherwise I find the question to be extremely boring and arbitrary.

Comment: I actually think it's a cool idea.

Comment: @ncmathsadist Maybe the premise of the sequence is "cool", but until someone gives me a reason to believe that anything interesting would come out of this (e.g similarity to another sequence or some theory), I just don't see what we gain out of studying a sequence so arbitrarily defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a partial sum $s$ whose last term is $\dfrac{1}{n^2}$, the next term is $\dfrac{1}{m^2}$ where $m=\max(n+1,\bigg\lceil \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-s}}\bigg\rceil)$.

The first few terms correspond to these $n$:

```
3
4
5
6
11
54
519
59429
22852059
244010721780
```

You need multiple precision to compute this. $59429$ is as far as you can go with standard double precision floating point.

Answer (score 0):

So, essentially,
you have a decreasing positive sequence
$(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$
such that
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$
converges
and
$a_m < \sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty} a_n
$
for all $n$.

Let
$s(m)
=\sum_{n=1}^{m} a_n
$.

Then you want to show that,
for $r > 0$,
$s(m) < r < s(m+1)$
for some $m$,
there is a subsequence
$(a_{n_j})_{j=1}^{\infty}$
with
$n_j < n_{j+1}$
such that
$r
=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_{n_j}
$.

This would seem to follow
from the fact that
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$
converges
and the growth restriction
on the $a_n$.